# what does an app do to satisfy the dock bounce?

Tags: macos, dock, icon, x11

What does an application have to do that satisfies the dock system so it stops bouncing the app's icon?

I am writing an X11 app that runs via XQuartz. I can create an app bundle with an icon for the Desktop such that my app runs fine when I double-click it, but the icon in the dock bounces forever.

I am aware of the dock feature that allows turning off bouncing for all apps, that's not what I need.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: Perhaps all apps set a “ready” flag so the icon then stops bouncing.

Answer (score 2):

An application's icon will bounce in the macOS Dock until the application enters its main event loop and begins responding to user input.

See [How do I make the dock icon stop bouncing after my app wrapper script starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008267/295396)

Answer (score 0):

The answer: the dock icon will bounce until the parent app process exits.

Therefore the solution is to fork a new process for your real app and have the parent exit. That's all there is to it.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution (and told us about it), but there has got to be a better way than that! Most apps don't just start a sub-process and exit.